# .htaccess correct complex redirection

Tags: .htaccess

I am attempting to create an seo friendly url system.

Sample:
    `/category` would get information from `cat.php?cat=category`

My issue is that I want to keep that url and be able to do something like the following

```
/category?page=2&sub=1
or 
/category/?page=2&sub=1
```

I was able to get the folders to redirect to the cat.php file but I cant seem to figure out the second half.

```
#Create redirect for all nonexistant folders to the category file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? cat.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you this should be what you need.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]
```

So if you were to use a URL like this

```
http://www.yoursite.com/category?page=2&sub=1
```

The `RewriteRule`will direct it to `cat.php?cat=category&page=2&sub=1`

Comment: Thank You very much it works perfect except you missed the a / before the $ to remove the slash from the category at RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ cat.php?cat=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Yes that's right. That's because i actually wrote it as if you were going to use your first choice `/category?page=2&sub=1` which has no `/`. :) But I'm glad it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking the QSA flag at the very least. [Without QSA, the existing query string is simply replaced by the new query string](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA).

Comment: I understand I may need QSA but how would I implement when I dont know the directory

Comment: What directory? It was my understanding you wanted `/category/?page=2&sub=1` to end up as `cat.php?cat=category&page=2&sub=1`?

Comment: category could be one of 50 different categories and our system allows adding more categories